# How to pass "*" in command line arguments.?

Tags: linux, shell

see i have below code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        int i=0;
        for(i=1;i<argc-1;i++)
          printf(" %s \n",argv[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

compiles and run as follows

```
gcc test.c
./a.out 1 * 2
```

and now its o/p is scarred..!

o/p is :

```
 1 
 a.out 
 Desktop 
 Documents 
 Downloads 
 ipmsg.log 
 linux-fusion-3.2.6 
 Music 
 Pictures 
 Public 
 Templates 
 test.c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could invoke your test using

```
./a.out 1 \* 2
```

if you want to pass * as an argument.  You can also use single quotes `'*'` (as suggested by Esa) or double quotes `"*"`.

Note also that your loop currently ignores the last argument.  Use `i<argc` as your exit condition if this isn't deliberate.

Comment: I'd +1 this twice for also pointing out the possible exit condition issue if I could

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes around the asterisk:

```
./a.out 1 '*' 2
```

This should prevent your shell from interpreting it as a special character.